# Javascript: Best way to split an array if sum meet a condition as it loops through the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array

```
[ 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1 ]
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get what I need to do. I'm trying to figure out if I need to use reduce method, do..while loop, or something else.

First, I need to loop through the array. Second, I need to sum up as I loop through the array. If the sum is `0` then push the elements that adds up to `0` to new array.

For example, if the first two elements in the array is `[1, -1]` add up to `0`, then push [1, -1] to new array to get this result:

```
[[1, -1], [-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1]]
```

Therefore, I thought that maybe the `reduce` method is the best candidate for the job. Here is my attempt:

```
let hikeArr = [ 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1 ];

let newArr = hikeArr.reduce((a, b) => {
        let sum = a + b;
        if( sum == 0) {
            a.push(b)
        }
        return a;
    }, []);
    console.log("newArr", newArr);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what about the leftover if no sum of zero is reachable?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `reduce` will work too well, since you need to keep track of 3 separate things: the current sum, the combined array, and the array in progress. (Even if only a single object had to be kept track of, it [wouldn't really be appropriate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) either IMO) Use outside variables and a `for` loop instead:

```js
let hikeArr = [ 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1 ];

const output = [];
let sum = 0;
let subarr = [];
for (const num of hikeArr) {
  sum += num;
  subarr.push(num);
  if (sum === 0) {
    output.push(subarr);
    subarr = [];
  }
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This is the best solution IMHO. Other answers use `reduce` but it seems quite "forced". I think simple `for` statement is the cleanest and most straight forward way.

Answer (score 1):

You need a temporary array, preferably with a closure along with a variable for the sum by using reduce.

```js
let array = [1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1],
    result = array.reduce(((temp, sum) => (r, v) => {
        temp.push(v);
        sum += v;
        if (!sum) {
            r.push(temp);
            temp = [];
        }
        return r;
    })([], 0), []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: is this reduce in a reduce? `((temp, sum) => (r, v) => `

Comment: it is a closure/IIFE in a reduce.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply done using `Array.reduce`.

On `Array.reduce` callback, for the input `current value`, you can push that value to `subArr` and calculate the sum.

And once `sum` reaches `0`, push the `subArr` to `main result` and format them to initial value.

```js
let hikeArr = [ 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1 ];


let subArr = [];
let sum = 0;
const result = hikeArr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  subArr.push(cur);
  sum += cur;
  if (sum === 0) {
    acc.push(subArr);
    subArr = [];
    sum = 0;
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```